# Sending intent from InputMethodService

Tags: android, ime

I need to communicate with other app through my ime,i wanted to run this code:

```
 Intent intent=new Intent("someaction");
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        List activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;
```

and the if isIntentSafe to use startActivityForResult ,but i can't do it through IME because it is not an activity, any suggestions how can I do this ?

startActivity starts an activity from another app ,so if call startActivityForResult from there the result will stay there i will not see it in InputMethodService

Thank you

Comment: `InputMethodService` is a `Service`, which is a `Context`. what's wrong with your code?

Comment: i can't call startActivityForResult ,only startActivity.

Comment: then just start your own activity and call `startActivityForResult ` at `onCreate`

Comment: ok thank you !, and is there an option to hide it so the user won't see it.

Comment: user won't see it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346102/must-every-activity-have-a-layout