# Google Speech to Text from Notification

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, voice-recognition, speech

I've created a sort of permanent `notification`, and my goal is like this

1) User taps on the `notification`
2) `Google Speech to Text activity` starts and takes voice input
3) The input is converted to text and and a new activity starts, which shows that text.

Here's what I've tried so far--

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setContentTitle("Tap for voice input")
            .setContentText("Hi");

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    resultIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    resultIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    resultIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(MainActivity.this);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Now I know that I can process the results of the recognizer `Intent` normally by using `startActivityForResult(resultIntent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);`, and processing it in my `activity`.

but I have to pass my intent into a `pendingIntent` for the `notification`.

Any way I can achieve this?

**Edit 1:**

I can start a new activity, and then open voice Google voice prompt, but I want the converted string to be passed to my activity before it starts, like with an extra parameter in an intent...

Comment: I think the answer provided is most suitable for your needs - otherwise, if you want to get more technical, you can use the `SpeechRecognizer` class to get the speech input from a service and then pass the parameters to an Activity once it has completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an "invisible" `Activity` as mediator. It's possible to have Activities without UI, see for example [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17346615/5015207) by Emanuel Moecklin. So you can modify the flow of your app like this:

- User taps on the notification
- `Activity` without UI starts and calls `startActivityForResult()` to obtain the result for the STT conversion
- Google Speech to Text `Activity` starts and takes voice input
- The input is converted to text and sent as result to the UI-less `Activity`
- ... which in turn starts a new `Activity` which shows that text.