# (AppCompat) Activity without UI

Tags: android, android-activity, android-theme

As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346102/must-every-activity-have-a-layout?noredirect=1&lq=1), I know I am allowed to create an activity that has no user interface by declaring your activity like below:

```
<activity
    android:name=".NoUIActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
</activity>
```

My problem is NoUIActivity extends AppCompatActivity. If I use the `android:theme` line above, it gives me error saying I should use the corresponding AppCompat theme. Help please. Thanks!

Comment: Probably useful: https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/11/02/psa-android-6p0-theme.nodisplay-regression.html

Comment: If there is no UI, just extend `Activity`, instead of `AppCompatActivity`. What are you gaining from using `AppCompatActivity` in this case? Also, as the blog post that Mr. Kent pointed to mentions, you probably want `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar`, instead of `Theme.NoDisplay`.

Comment: I have a prebuilt activity handler class that extends AppCompatActivity. All my other activities are subclasses of it including the non ui activity. I will just probably make an exception for this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your activity should look like:

```
public class NoUIActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        setContentView(R.layout.activity_no_uiactivity);
    }
}
```

And in AndroidManifest.xml declare activity like:

```
<activity
            android:name=".NoUIActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:exported="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an app with single activity
2. Delete the layout xml which you don't need
3. Remove `setContentView` line (generated by Android Studio),in Activity's `onCreate()`
   method
4. Call `finish()` when done